# UIPanGestureRecognizer right and left tableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipangesturerecognizer

Right now, I am developing an iOS app that uses a subclass of `UITableviewCell` that uses UIPanGestureRecognizer to slide left and right but FavoritesTableViewCell don't work correctly and error.

> error: fatal error: NSCoding not supported

**UITableViewCell.swift**

```
class FavoritesTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var favimage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var texten: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var textfn: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var price: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var likeimage: UIImageView!

var originalCenter = CGPoint()
var deleteOnDragRelease = false
    override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("NSCoding not supported")
}
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    let recognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer (target: self, action: "handlePan:")
    recognizer.delegate = self
    addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
        }
//MARK: - horizontal pan gesture methods
func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    // 1
    if recognizer.state == .Began {
        // when the gesture begins, record the current center location
        originalCenter = center
    }
    // 2
    if recognizer.state == .Changed {
        let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self)
        center = CGPointMake(originalCenter.x + translation.x, originalCenter.y)
        // has the user dragged the item far enough to initiate a delete/complete?
        deleteOnDragRelease = frame.origin.x < -frame.size.width / 2.0
    }
    // 3
    if recognizer.state == .Ended {
        // the frame this cell had before user dragged it
        let originalFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.origin.y,
                                   width: bounds.size.width, height: bounds.size.height)
        if !deleteOnDragRelease {
            // if the item is not being deleted, snap back to the original location
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {self.frame = originalFrame})
        }
    }
}

override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if let panGestureRecognizer = gestureRecognizer as? UIPanGestureRecognizer {
        let translation = panGestureRecognizer.translationInView(superview!)
        if fabs(translation.x) > fabs(translation.y) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    return false
}}
```

[and my favourite storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0drBl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Comment or remove this:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("NSCoding not supported")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is OK, if u create the cell by code.

---

If u use storyboard to create the cell, then `required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {` will be called.

Surely, `fatalError("NSCoding not supported")`

---

U can also use this

```
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
}
```

do the Initialization in `awakeFromNib()`

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    let recognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer (target: self, action: "handlePan:")
    recognizer.delegate = self
    addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
        }
```